# uniform convergence of the sine function

Tags: uniform-convergence

Find if $\sin  \frac{nx}{n+x}$ converges uniformly in $[0, K]$ and $[K, \infty)$

I'm a bit stuck, I tried writing

$\sup|\sin\frac{nx}{n+x}-\sin x|=\sup|\sin\frac{2nx+x^2}{2(n+x)}\cos\frac{x^2}{2(n+x)}|$
using the diference formula and finding a derivative, but it seems to be too complicated to be useful. Surely there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, but for the case of compact intervals isn't convergence necessarily uniform, since the limit is continuous?

Comment: If I'm not wrong the continuity is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

Comment: I knew that, but I knew there was a converse with some extra conditions. However, I've looked it up and found that the additional conditions are compactness and monotony, and the second fails in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $[0,K]$ use the mean value theorem to get
$$
\Bigl|\sin\frac{n\,x}{n+x}-\sin x\Bigr|\le\Bigl|\frac{n\,x}{n+x}-x\Bigr|=\frac{x^2}{n+x}\le\frac{K^2}{n-K}
$$
for all $n>K$. The convergence is thus uniform.

On $[K,\infty)$ choose $x=n\,\pi$ ($n>K$):
$$
\Bigl|\sin\frac{n\,x}{n+x}-\sin x\Bigr|_{x=n\pi}=\Bigl|\sin\frac{n\,\pi}{1+\pi}\Bigr|,
$$
that does not converge to $0$. The convergence is not uniform.